# How to use test data (json files) given by one build in subsequent builds?

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins

I have few json files which get updated during jenkins build. I need to use updated data in the next jenkins build.
When I run build from jenkins second time, jenkins is not taking data which was generated in previous build. And when I see my repository in CodeCommit, first build is not updating the json files.
My requirement is to use the data in second build which is generated from first build.

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing my experience in this type of situation..

I added a shell script that triggers after the build's success. Which will move your JSON file to a generic location.

here is an example of post-build. You can even execute the shell script.

Image : https://issues.jenkins.io/secure/attachment/40480/JENKINS-48169_configuration.png

And you have to read the JSON file from the generic location so every build will get latest updated data